# window.open for printing and call a field through database

Tags: php, click, row, window.open

sorry I have no specific title for this problem,

I want to print a form with window.open method and this is some piece of script :

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$test = mysql_query("select * from dataorder order by idorder desc limit 1 ");


if (!test)
die ("Error... " .mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($test))
{
echo "ID number   : $row[idorder] <br/><br/>";
echo "Name        : $row[name] <br/><br/>";  
echo "<div>";
echo "<input  type=button name=back    value='back'onClick='parent.location='reserve.php''>";   
echo '<input  type="submit"
          class="btn btn-success"
          name="print" value="print"
       onClick="window.open("print.php?idorder="'.$row['idorder'].'","scrollwindow","top=200,left=350,width=680px,height=500")" 
        style="text-decoration:none">';
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

the "print" button can appear but no response when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have multiple quote issues (plus space issues) that prevent the `onClick` from working correctly -

```
echo "<input  type=button name=back    value='back'onClick='parent.location='reserve.php''>"; 
                  ^      ^    ^    ^              ^                                      ^
echo '<input  type="submit"
      class="btn btn-success"
      name="print" value="print"
   onClick="window.open("print.php?idorder="'.$row['idorder'].'","scrollwindow","top=200,left=350,width=680px,height=500")"
                        ^                  ^                   ^ ^            ^ ^                                       ^ 
    style="text-decoration:none">';
```

try something like this -

```
echo '<input type="button" name="back" value="back" onClick="parent.location=\'reserve.php\'">';   
echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="print" value="print"
       onClick="window.open(\'print.php?idorder='.$row['idorder'].'\',\'scrollwindow\',\'top=200,left=350,width=680px,height=500\')" 
    style="text-decoration:none">';
```